# Is it possible to catch hardware errors in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, exception

This piece of C++ code crashes because it contains division-by-zero error:

```
int main()
{
    try {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1 / i;
    } catch(...) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to catch errors like this on different platforms? If you only know some of the platforms then you may answer about those you know.

I have a basic idea about SEH on Windows and signals on Linux, but I'm not sure whether there is a method to catch all kinds of hardware errors just like software errors in C++.

Finally, it looks like division-by-zero exceptions can be caught in Python:

```
try:
    i = 0
    j = 1 / i
except:
    pass
```

And in Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 1 / i;
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

So what prevents them from being caught in C++?

Comment: It's an undefined behavior, it's not an exception

Comment: You would have better chances to get this answered if you would narrow it down to a single platform. It's quite broad as it stands.

Comment: What prevents them being caught in C++ is that C++ has decided to go "as fast as possible, even if that means different platforms behave differently".  Thus a platform where 1/0 just left all the registers unchanged would be fine.  Java and Python have decided to go "all platforms behave the same", so there has to be a check for zero before doing a divide.

Comment: Platform independently? No. The C++ language doesn't have any support for this. This is necessarily platform-specific, as you allude to in the question. Unless you narrow it down to a specific platform, this is the best answer that you're going to get. And I don't think it's an actual answer, so I'm voting to close the question as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

C++11 defines floating point error handling:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling

and

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions